# Why am I getting CredentialsProviderError creating a presigned url for s3 via lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-iam-policy

I am trying to create presigned urls for clients to upload files via s3. I want these files to be created using lambda so I can verify client authorisation prior to generating the url.

When I run the code locally, everything works perfectly. However, when deployed to lambda I get a CredentialsProviderError I have attached full permissions over my bucket to my lambda role via both my lambda role IAM and also in bucket permissions.

The code I am using is taken from [Create a presigned URL for Amazon S3 using an AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example_s3_Scenario_PresignedUrl_section.html) and is as below:

```
const createPresignedUrlWithoutClient = async (key) => {
const url = parseUrl(`https://${BUCKET_NAME}.s3.${LOCATION}.amazonaws.com/${key}`);
const presigner = new S3RequestPresigner({
    credentials: fromIni(),
    region: LOCATION,
    sha256: Hash.bind(null, "sha256"),
});

const signedUrlObject = await presigner.presign(
    new HttpRequest({ ...url, method: "PUT" }),
);
return formatUrl(signedUrlObject);
```

};

Comment: what is the exact error? (cloudwatch logs)  and the code will help.

Comment: I've added the code above. The logs say "Profile default could not be found or parsed in shared credentials file". Is this because I am using fromIni? Should I be using the createPresignedUrlWithClient method instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fromIni()` would only work in an AWS Lambda environment if you also packaged a credentials INI file into your Lambda function's deployment artifact. And even then it would be in a different location on the file system than the default location `fromIni()` will be looking at.

I suggest using `fromEnv()` in the AWS Lambda environment.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't understood what fromIni is doing technically. The general reccomendation for providing credentials to lambda is using IAM. Is there a way to use IAM permissions to provide my lambda with the ability to create presigned urls? I notice on the link I included it has another method which uses S3Client. Does this one allow for this functionality?

Comment: The credentials that are automatically exposed to your AWS Lambda function via environment variables will have the IAM permissions that you assigned to the Lambda function. That's why I recommended using `fromEnv()`. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-runtime

Comment: Using fromEnv solved it. Thanks for the clarification!